# AmazonCostExplorerClient has Status = WaitingForActivation

Tags: amazon-web-services, cost-management

I am trying to query cost data from Cost API. The response status is `WaitingForActivation` even IAM user  has the permission `Billing` and I can access Cost Explorer from `AWS Cost Management Console`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. Forgot `await` before the call.